# Splitting field of $x^3-3x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know there is a trick in that you can use $\omega + \omega ^{-1}$ where $\omega$ is a 9th root of unity but I can't see how this relates. I know this question has already been asked on here but there was no solution given using the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = z + \frac 1z\\
x^3 - 3x + 1 = z^3 + \frac 1{z^3} + 1 = \frac {1}{z^3} (z^3 + e^\frac {2\pi i}{3})(z^3 + e^\frac {-2\pi i}{3})\\
x^3 - 3x + 1 = (x + 2\cos \frac {2\pi}{9})(x + 2\cos \frac {4\pi}{9})(x + 2\cos \frac {8\pi}{9})$

Comment: In general it is the [conductor-discriminant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor-discriminant_formula) that lets us compute the conductor $n$ (such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, here $n= 9$) of a Galois cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: How do you get from the 2nd line to the 3rd line?

Comment: Suppose $z = e^\frac {2\pi i}{9}$ then $\frac {1}{z} = e^\frac{-2\pi i}{9}$ and $z + \frac 1z = e^\frac{2\pi i}{9} + e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{9}} = 2 \cos \frac {2\pi i}9$

Comment: I think you meant $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$, I understand that, but what do you substitute in for the $\frac {1}{z^3}$ and so on

Comment: And does this mean that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9})$

Comment: $\mathbb Q [\cos \frac {2\pi}{9},\cos \frac {4\pi}{9}, \cos \frac {8\pi}{9}]$

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial is the minimal polynomial of $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$, and the conjugates of $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$ are $2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9}$ and $2\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}$. The cosine duplication formula gives $\cos(2x)=2\cos(x)^2-1$, hence the map $z\mapsto z^2-2$ acts on the roots of such polynomial by cycling them.

Comment: How do you know that it is the minimal polynomial of $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$, is there a method to work it out?

Comment: You mean the unique automorphism sending the root $\alpha$ to $\alpha^2-2$, right?  Not the map $z \mapsto z^2 - 2$ which isn't an automorphism since it doesn't fix $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I meant that the set of roots can be written as $$\{\alpha,\alpha^2-2,(\alpha^2-2)^2-2\},$$ but the intended message was exactly the one you are mentioning.